# Yaml not passing validator

Tags: yaml

According to a tutorial I'm using for aws.  This Yaml file should work.  In atom I have YAML grammar selected and it's not showing any errors.  However this is not passing YAML validator online and gives me an error in AWS.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong with it?

```
version: 1
cron:
 — name: "shopify"
   url: "/shopify"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an [em dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html) (—) instead of a hyphen (-) on line 3.

Comment: Wow, nice work on the nearly identical answer a few seconds later. :D

Comment: Yeah, I edited accordingly. It's very hard to tell the difference between an em dash and an en dash in a monospaced font! :)

Comment: I just pasted one after the other under OP's mystery character in a text editor to more easily compare length

Answer (score 1):

You have an em dash (—) instead of a hyphen (-) on the third line.